# EXC_BAD_ACCESS NSXMLParser using delegate on ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I have this code in parser DidendElement.

```
   [self setImageThumbnailLink:[NSMutableString stringWithString:imageLink]];
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(receiveImageLink:withParser:withParameter:)]){

        [_delegate receiveImageLink:[self imageThumbnailLink] withParser:nil withParameter:parameterPassed];
    }        
    else{            
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                    format:@"Delegate doesn't respond to receiveItems:"];
    }
```

When the code reach   [_delegate receiveImageLink:[self imageThumbnailLink] withParser:nil withParameter:parameterPassed];

EXC_BAD_ACCESS occur. I've tried what is wrong with it by trying to make each parameter nil. And EXC_BAD_ACCESS occur when the [self imageThumbnailLink] is passed to delegate.
How can i solve that?
I use [nonatomic,strong] for imageThumbnailLink. it is NSMutableString. 
If i use this code (not using variable):It is working fine.

```
 [_delegate receiveImageLink:@"http://www.....flower.jpg" withParser:nil withParameter:parameterPassed];
```

Thank you

Error Message in console:
Only
Current language: auto; currently objective-c (gdb).

This is the stack trace:
[image: error message (no error message in console)]

Comment: Please post the exact and complete error message from the console.

Comment: Im just a noob at this stuff, but perhaps you might try using [self setImageThumbnailLink:[NSMutableString stringWithString:imageLink]] in the first line (stringWithString instead of stringWithFormat).

Comment: already change it with stringWithString. but still EXC_Bad_access.

Comment: The image that was added is not the console error message, it is the call stack. Post the console messages, open display the console - Menu:VIew:Debug Area:Activate Console.

Comment: as i said earlier in the comment from you answer, the error message 
I've edit the error message to make it clear.
only

Current language: auto; currently objective-c (gdb).

Answer (score 0):

Lacking the complete error message here is best guess:

Probably `[self imageThumbnailLink]` is bad or parameterPassed. Try separating the statement into two for debugging:
Ex:

```
NSLog(@"parameterPassed: %@", parameterPassed);
NSString *imageLink = [self imageThumbnailLink];
NSLog(@"imageLink: %@", imageLink);
[_delegate receiveImageLink:imageLink withParser:nil withParameter:parameterPassed];
```

In general when  trying to debug an error separating the components of a compound statement is a good first step.

Comment: the imagelink is printed in the console and it is definitely not nil. and still get the exc_bad_access :(. There is no error message in the console. just this. Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb). and the exc_bad_access point to certain address.

Comment: parameterPassed is good, because when i hardcoded the imageLink
[_delegate receiveImageLink:@"http://www.....flower.jpg" withParser:nil withParameter:parameterPassed];

it is working fine.
So what my guess is, the imageLink already release by arc?

Comment: Perhaps try stringWithString instead of stringWithFormat when setting the image link in the first line?

Comment: Or just set the string: `[self setImageThumbnailLink:imageLink];` there is nothing gained with `stringWithString` except in this case creating a mutable string.